# try to import query, show error

Tags: sql, sql-server

i try to backup my database.
so when i backup it working but when i import the sql to database it show error

that the sql export`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('AIc', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE AIc
CREATE TABLE AIc
(
IDAIC int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(10,2),
name nvarchar (50)  
);

INSERT INTO AIc (IDAIC,name) Values 
(10,'asaf'),
(12,'shazar');
```

the error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AIc' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: When you googled the error, it didn't explain it?   What about it don't you understand?

Comment: how i can insert it otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Since the `IDAIC` column is an `IDENTITY` column, you have two choices:

**(1)** you just *don't supply* a value and let SQL Server handle the `INSERT` of those values itself (that's the preferred, default way of inserting data):

```
INSERT INTO AIc(name) Values('asaf'), ('shazar');
```

or **(2)** if you **must** specify those values yourself, you need to enable the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` first (and turn it off again after the `INSERT`) :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIC ON

INSERT INTO AIc (IDAIC, name) 
VALUES (10, 'asaf'), (12, 'shazar');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIC OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on identity insert on the table like this so that you can specify your own identity values.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('AIc', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE AIc
    CREATE TABLE AIc
    (
       IDAIC int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(10,2),
       name nvarchar (50)  
    );
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIc ON

    INSERT INTO AIc (IDAIC,name) Values 
    (10,'asaf'),
    (12,'shazar');

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIc OFF
```

Comment: This is missing the option to not supply the identity, which is a more desirable way of doing this action

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting values for `IDAIC` that is an identity column.

You can turn on identity insert on the table like this so that you can specify your own identity values.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIc ON

INSERT INTO AIc 
/*Note the column list is REQUIRED here, not optional*/
(IDAIC,name) 
Values 
(10,'asaf'),
(12,'shazar');


SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIc OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('AIc', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE AIc
CREATE TABLE AIc
(
    IDAIC int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(10,2),
    name nvarchar (50)  
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT AIc ON;

INSERT INTO AIc (IDAIC,name) Values 
(10,'asaf'),
(12,'shazar');
```